# My SQL Query is creating more records with an INNER Join

Tags: sql-server

Below is the query I have been using until I was asked to join another table below called `Disiposition`.

```
DispositionID    Disposition
------------------------------------
    1            All Good
    2            Used with problems 
    3            Rework
    4            Scrapped
    5            Return to Vendor
```

The `Rejections` table (already linked to this query also has a `DispositionID` column. All I was trying to do is join the table above to show which of the 5 dispositions was applied to each inspection. Every time I try something, the total number of records found go from 6,841 to 34,205. So it looks like it is assigning one of each of the above dispositions to the original 6,841 records, when I know that there is only on that has been assigned when the record was added to the database. Any help would be greatly.

```
SELECT 
    qalog.qalid,
    qalog.groupid,
    qalog.logdate,
    qalog.sonumber,
    qalog.partnumber,
    qalog.partnotes,
    qalog.travelerqty,
    qalog.euser,
    qalog.itid,
    qalog.trackingnumber,
    qalog.mdr,
    qalog.expirationdate,
    qalog.ponumber,
    qalog.receiptno,
    qalog.reasonid,
    qalog.rrno,
    rejections.numdiscrp,
    rejections.rrid,
    rejectreason.reason,
    productgroups.groupname,
    disposition.disposition
FROM   
    qalog
INNER JOIN 
    rejections ON qalog.qalid = rejections.qalid
INNER JOIN 
    rejectreason ON rejectreason.rrid = rejections.rrid

INNER JOIN 
    Disposition on Disposition.DispostionID = Rejections.Disposition.ID

INNER JOIN 
    productgroups ON productgroups.pgid = qalog.groupid
WHERE  
    (qalog.logdate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE()))
    AND (qalog.itid = '3')
    AND (rejectreason.groupid = '0')
     OR (qalog.logdate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE()))
    AND (qalog.itid = '3')   
    AND (rejectreason.groupid = '3')
ORDER BY 
    qalog.qalid
```

Comment: This question has changed fundamentally from the original one asked. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Getdate and dateadd functions do not exist in mysql, only in ms sql server. Replaced the incorrect tag.

Answer (score 1):

Take a really close look at your join condition:

```
INNER JOIN disposition ON 
  rejections.dispositionid = 
  rejections.dispositionid
```

I’ve reformatted your code hopefully to make it easier to see

After you correct the problem, if you’re still getting more rows out than you intended it’s and indication that there are multiple rows in the table you’re joining that match to rows in the tables you already have in the query. This indicates you need to add more conditions so that the row matching is 1:1

For example if there is a date indicating when a disposition was valid from/to and it’s a business rule that the current disposition has a null date you join on ID and also `datexyz is null`

As to why your original form (the mistake in the join) caused rows to multiply, as a predicate it is always true, realising what we call a Cartesian product. The number of rows you end up with is the number of rows on the left multiplied by the number of rows on the right. Every row ends up crossed with every other row. It can be a useful technique sometimes, though it’s not in this case. As has been commented elsewhere, if you unexpectedly get duplicates while coding you should focus on working out where they crept in rather than using distinct or group to remove them again. In nearly all cases they can be prevented at source rather than quashed later and it’s always preferred as it makes your database’s life easier

Comment: Actually the part below was accidently copied into my original post because I was experimenting with it. It isn't in my original code. I just need to know how to re-write it to get the dispositions to appear and not create one for each of the 5 dispositions.

Comment: INNER JOIN disposition ON 
                  rejections.dispositionid = 
                  rejections.dispositionid

Comment: Your join condition specifies the same column on the left and right side of the predicate. It is the effective equivalent of `inner join othertable on 1=1` and is hence always true for every row combination

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion

looking to your ()  sequence in where seems you have two ime the same condition in WHERE

```
    WHERE  ( qalog.logdate >= Dateadd(year, -3, Getdate()) )
     OR ( qalog.logdate >= Dateadd(year, -3, Getdate()) )
```

you could avoid

If the OR clause is related  to different rejectreason.groupid  yo should use
(seems also that you have removed  the join with disposition  this is added but if you don't need  you can remove)

```
   SELECT   qalog.qalid,
            qalog.groupid,
            qalog.logdate,
            qalog.sonumber,
            qalog.partnumber,
            qalog.partnotes,
            qalog.travelerqty,
            qalog.euser,
            qalog.itid,
            qalog.trackingnumber,
            qalog.mdr,
            qalog.expirationdate,
            qalog.ponumber,
            qalog.receiptno,
            qalog.reasonid,
            qalog.rrno,
            rejections.numdiscrp,
            rejections.rrid,
            rejectreason.reason,
            productgroups.groupname,
            disposition.disposition
    FROM   qalog

    INNER JOIN disposition on disposition.dispositionid = rejections.dispositionid

    INNER JOIN rejections ON qalog.qalid = rejections.qalid
    INNER JOIN rejectreason ON rejectreason.rrid = rejections.rrid
    INNER JOIN productgroups ON productgroups.pgid = qalog.groupid
    WHERE   qalog.logdate >= Dateadd(year, -3, Getdate()) 
    AND  qalog.itid = '3' 
    AND  ( rejectreason.groupid = '0'   OR rejectreason.groupid = '3' )
    ORDER  BY qalog.qalid
```

Comment: I think the actual focus should be on why he is getting duplicates in the first place!

Comment: @CaiusJard I was looking to the query  for several issue  .. you have found an important one  .... if you think your previous comment is not useful you can delete ..

Comment: Do please keep in mind that it’s nearly always a terrible idea, and the sign of poor code, to use distinct to quash duplicates. As an educated and well respected community member with considerable reputation, please take careful responsibility when teaching concepts to newbies

Comment: The to where conditions are different in that they use a different groupid

Comment: I edited my original to take out those lines that were accidentally in there. It now reflex what I originally worked well. But now they want me to show the disposition, which I don't know enough about sql to make that happen

Comment: @Steve  for what is related to the OR clause  i have updated  thw asnwer  with a suggestion  ..  let me know

Comment: Hi - the OR clause allowes me to include every case where the "(rejectreason.groupid = '0')" and every case where " (rejectreason.groupid = '3')". That part works for me. The part I having difficulty I with is getting the table added that assigns the DispositionID to each line. Right now, all I can get it to do is assign  unique DispositionID to each line, when I know they all only have one of the 5 in the original list assigned to them.

Comment: how the dispositionID is related  between the tables ?  is based on  INNER JOIN disposition on disposition.dispositionid = rejections.dispositionid as i suggested in my query or is based on others tables and columns ..?

Comment: I've edited the original code to show what finally worked. I added the 3rd INNER JOIN and that seemed to work (it has a space before and after the command). The SELECT statement also has "Disposition.Disposition" at the end to show the column at the end of my new query results.

Comment: seems as i have suggested in my answer  with inner join between  disposition and rejections .... what 's the difference  ..